# Why my div wont float to the right edge

Tags: css, html

i have two div like this

```
<div id="pos-bar">
  <div id="pointer"></div>
</div>
```

and the css is like this

```
#pos-bar {
 height: 10px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto; }

#pointer{
 height: 4px;
 width: 180px;
 float: right;
 background-color: #57c5a0; }
```

i try to make "pointer" div to float to the right edge of "pos-bar" div, but with this code it only floated to the middle of "pos-bar" div. And whenever i try to add margin left to "pointer", the div go down, not in the "pos-bar div anymore. Why is this happening?

Comment: It is floated to the right. The text inside will still be left aligned, which is why it might seem like the inner div is middle aligned.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vEQt3/2/ The `div` is floated right, the text is left aligned

Comment: Why is it not floated to the right on your side? are you joking? What kind of browser did you try with (name, version) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fyou want `#pointer` to float all the way right, you need to expand the parent's width to the total width of window.

For this, you can remove `width:960px;` on `#post-bar` it will then expand by default to the total width of it's container and it's child (`#pointer`) will be able to float all the way right.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/gRF2y/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `float:right` to `pos-bar` div. Child get out the parents if child and parent not share some important css characteristics. Like absolute/relative positions.